# Maximum I/O Data Transfer if DMA is used

Tags: operating-systems, memory-hardware

I was reading lecture notes of [Universiti Malaysia Perlis](http://portal.unimap.edu.my/portal/page/portal30/Lecturer%20Notes/KEJURUTERAAN_KOMPUTER/Semester%201%20Sidang%20Akademik%2020102011/EKT%20423%20Operating%20System/Others/Tutorial_1_Ans.pdf) when I am came across following question:

> A computer consists of a CPU and an I/O device $D$ connected to main
>   memory $M$ via a shared bus with a data bus width of one word
>   $(16-bits)$. The CPU can execute a maximum of $10^6$ instructions per
>   second. An average instruction requires $five $ processor cycles,
>   $three$  of which use the memory bus. A memory read or write operation
>   uses $one$  processor cycle. Suppose that the CPU is continuously
>   executing *“background”* programs that require $95$% of its
>   instruction execution rate but not any I/O instructions.  Now very
>   large blocks of data are to be transferred between $M $ and $D$.
>
> **Estimate the rate if DMA transfer is used.**

P.S. Assume that one processor cycle equals one bus cycle.

The answer says:

$$10^6 * (0.05 * 5 + 0.95 * 2) = 2.15 * 10^6$$

**Can someone explain the reasoning behind the answer ?**

I could understand that $0.05$ is percent of time devoted by CPU 
and $0.95$ is the percent of time devoted by DMA, but what about $5$ and $2$ ?
If it has something to do with cycles, then I did not understand the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading more about it and reading the question again and again, I understood the logic

> The question says that on an average an instruction requires $5$
>   $cycles$ and the CPU is busy $95$% of the time in executing those
>   instructions. Out of these $5\ cycles$, $3\ cycles$ are needed for memory operations. During this time $DMA$ cannot access the memory.

So only $2\ cycles$ are left for $DMA$ to use for 95% of the time.
For 95% time DMA uses
$$0.95 * 2\ cycles$$

For rest 5% time, CPU isn't executing instructions, so all cycles are available, so DMA uses
$$0.05 * 5\ cycles$$

Total cycles available for DMA
$$(0.05 * 5 + 0.95 * 2)\ cycles$$

In $1 second$, CPU can execute  $10^6$ instructions. So rate of transfer is

$$
10^6 * (0.05 * 5 + 0.95 * 2) = 2.15 * 10^6 
$$

Answer (score 0):

we can see it like-wise also (I guess), i made it like a reasoning maths questions :P

In DMA , we don't need direct intervention of CPU , its DMAC which helps in controlling the data transfer.

let us take , CPU is fed with 100 instructions (replace those 10^6, as it says , cpu can execute - MIPS).
For 100 instns  it will require ~500 cycles .
Now divide this into two sections
so for 95 * 5 cycles , DMA will use 95 * 2 cycles (as during 3 cycles mem bus is busy ), and the remaining cycles 25 (=500-95 * 5) will be consumed by the IO device. now sum up (95 * 2)+(5instn * 5cycles)=2.15 (words per second)
just multiply it with 10^6 for the case when 10^6 instn are fed.(2.15 * 10^6)